# Android Studio, System error when i run my application

Tags: java, android

i'm running my app on android 5.1 API 22. Its too old and my app doesnt work propertly. Android studio give me this error. any application I run on andoid 5.1 give me this error

- i disable instant run on android studio.
- i try another phone with android 5.1.
- i think problem isn't into the code, but in android studio.

this is the error:
Click ("[image: this text appears when you mouse over]")!

Comment: Please, [don't just post an image of your error message](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Include your error message and a [mcve] **as text**.

Answer (score 0):

I see from the description and error log, you are not able to install the app on your device. But I am not able to get exact context of the problem you are facing.

My recommendation would be:

It is because of old debug-apk cached in your android studio. I would recommend to Build -> Clean Project -> Rebuild Project and Install Apk. This way, it will clean the old apk and rebuild new one and install it in your device.